# Rails - Send alert to another user when they are assigned a new client (without refreshing their page)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a User model using devise and a Trader model. I want to send a popup message or alert to users whenever they are assigned a new Trader.

Managers can assign traders to users so the assign process is done by a different user than the user receiving a new trader.

How to I make the manager's 'assign' action send an alert to the specific user who has been assigned a new trader? They will be logged in but I don't want them to have to refresh their page

**Assign method in traders_controller.rb**

```
if @trader.save
  // Send alert to user if @trader.user == current_user 
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully created trader." // flash message for manager
  redirect_to traders_path
  return
else
  render :new
  return
end
```

Comment: What version of Rails?

Comment: @aridlehoover I'm using Rails 5

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a socket to push the new information to the appropriate client. If you're using Rails 5, you can use ActionCable. You'll want to subscribe the user to a channel specific to them, then publish information on that channel to update the user. Of course, your front-end will need to know what to do with the data.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#client-server-interactions-subscriptions

If you're on an older version of Rails, take a look at this article:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/implementing-web-sockets-in-a-rails-4-fb45696f8d8c.

Comment: Great answer. An alternative to this could be integrating with a service that can handle the hard parts for you. I've used pusher.com in the past, and was quite happy with it. You could also implement polling on the client-side by checking for messages at some interval, but this is quite wasteful of both client and server resources, but a good quick-n-dirty solution you don't need more infrastructure to handle.